# C# Interactive Console.Readkey() hangs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, console, interactive

When I type Console.Readkey() on the C# interactive window on Visual Studio 2015, it just hangs (typing any number of characters does not seem to do anything). Is this an incorrect setting or am I not understanding how the Interactive Window works with the Console?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Console.Readkey()

That's it.

Comment: You have nothing else in your file other than `Console.ReadKey()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

c# interactive currently doesn't support redirecting input so if you use any of the Console.Read Methods it will just freeze, you can fix this by clicking the reset button.

Comment: Hi, so is there any workaround for existing code that uses the Read methods?

Comment: Could you show me why you need to use Console.ReadKey() in c# interactive in the first place?

Comment: Just happens to be static research methods that used to run in Console programs which are far more convenient to run interactively. Certainly can be rewritten differently for the repl. Just trying to see if there is any way to make it work without extra work.

Comment: you can rewrite them to get the values they need as args, as far as i know there isn't any way around this.